# Adding an interval of 1 calendar month to a date

Tags: vertica

I would like to add 1 calendar month to a date, ignoring number of days in the month. i.e. `add_month('2015-02-23')` returns `2015-03-23` and `add_month('2015-05-23')` returns `2015-06-23`

It seems like I could use `INTERVAL '1 month'` to do this, but I was surprised to find that whenever I do this, it adds 30 days to my input i.e. functionally the same as `INTERVAL '30 days'`. Does this happen for you too? What should I do instead to increment by 1 calendar month?

Examples:

```
SELECT DATE('2015-04-23') + INTERVAL '1 month'
```

returns `2015-05-23`
while

```
SELECT DATE('2015-05-23') + INTERVAL '1 month'
```

returns `2015-06-22`!

Comment: This seems like Vertica-specific behavior.  At the very least, it works correctly on Postgres 9.3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This behavior is due to Vertica being modeled on [SQL 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2008) in which `1 MONTH` is a static 30 days, not a "smart month."

```
dbadmin=> SELECT INTERVAL '1 MONTH';
 ?column?
----------
 30
(1 row)
```

In order to get the desired behavior, you should use `INTERVALYM`:

```
dbadmin=> SELECT INTERVALYM '1 MONTH';
 ?column?
----------
 0-1
(1 row)

dbadmin=> SELECT DATE('2015-05-23') + INTERVALYM '1 MONTH';
      ?column?
---------------------
 2015-06-23 00:00:00
(1 row)
```

[Read more](https://community.dev.hp.com/t5/Vertica-Forum/INTERVAL-MONTH/td-p/227072)